# CXF Swagger2Feature adding global parameters

Tags: cxf, swagger

I have two global parameters in request, and I work on the swagger2Feature,so I  try to add two global parameters with the following code,but failed. How can I do it? Thanks any helps.

```
@Bean
    public Server rsServer() {
        final JAXRSServerFactoryBean endpoint = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        endpoint.setProviders(Arrays.asList(new JacksonJsonProvider(), new 
     InvokeFaultExceptionMapper()));
        endpoint.setBus(bus);
        endpoint.setAddress("/");
        endpoint.setServiceBeans(Arrays.<Object>asList(userController()));
        endpoint.setFeatures(Arrays.asList(new ExtendedSwagger2Feature()));
        return endpoint.create();
    }
    @Provider(value = Provider.Type.Feature, scope = Provider.Scope.Server)
    public static class ExtendedSwagger2Feature extends Swagger2Feature {
        @Override
        protected void addSwaggerResource(Server server, Bus bus) {
            super.addSwaggerResource(server, bus);

            BeanConfig config = (BeanConfig) ScannerFactory.getScanner();
            Swagger swagger = config.getSwagger();
            HeaderParameter headerParameter = new HeaderParameter();
            headerParameter.setName("apieui");
            headerParameter.setDefaultValue("123124141");
            swagger.addParameter("apieui", headerParameter);
            swagger.addParameter("tokens", new HeaderParameter());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying in your REST response you want apieui and tokens or in swagger.json?

Comment: yes, I want to add the two parameters on each request, but failed on the cxf swagger2Feature.